# local Repository taking huge space

Tags: repository, local

I am using gitlab for my project. There are 3 or 4 different repository which is taking huge space. Is there any better way to handle large space taken up? I have huge performance issue with computer. Local repository had to be deleted every time after branch work is completed to freeup space. This means, I am cloning the repo every time I need to work on new branch which is taking 30mins sometime which is again not helping and consuming huge time. I m also working on all three repository sequentially which means clone and delete 4 times for one assigned work which doesn't seem efficient.

Is it possible at all to keep all 4 repo in my local and still be efficient with space  and performance of computer ?

I am using VScode.

Any suggestion appreciated?

Best Strategies to keep local repository and yet efficient and avoid deleting every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems in the past with repos that contained many branches, tags, and commits. What helped me was using the [--single-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---no-single-branch) option of the clone command.

Since you mentioned you're using VS Code and GitLab, I'm also assuming you're using the GitLab WorkFlow VS Code extension. Sadly, I don't know how to specify the `--single-branch` option with that extension, but there should be a way.

Comment: I am using GitGraph. Sorry , I didn't mention it.  Do you have full command line for it? Will try and keep posted. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Not a problem. The full command would be something like `git clone --single-branch <url>` where you would replace <url> with your repo's URL.

I hope this works for you.